# What is the connection between decoherence and phase relationships?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

Every answer explaining decoherence brings up the concept of phase relationships, but I'm just not seeing the connection. In the double slit experiment, for example, it makes some intuitive sense to me that the surroundings would interact with different parts of the electron's wave-function differently, effectively creating a superposition of "electron was here and interacted here" and "electron was there and interacted there", but why can't these two possibilities still interfere?

edit: It makes sense to me that these two possibilities may just separate enough in Hilbert space to interact ever again, but I still don't see the connection to phases.

Comment: Are you aware of the time evolution of an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian? Also note that the description using wave functions is only applicable if we are dealing with so called pure states. If we have a incoherent superposition of states we have to use the density matrix to describe the system.

Answer (score 0):

Phase relationships in the case of a two-slit experiment mean that one can observe an interference pattern, which wouldn't appear, if electron simply took each path with some probability. When we observe which path the electron took, we collapse its wave function to a particular state (i.e. particular path) and the interference pattern disappears.